# Emacs - Can't get buffer-offer-save working

Tags: emacs, elisp, emacs23

I would like to have Emacs ask me whether I want to save a modified buffer, when that buffer is not associated with a file. To open a new buffer (not visiting a file) I have the following function in my .emacs file:

```
;; Creates a new empty buffer
(defun new-empty-buffer ()
  "Opens a new empty buffer."
  (interactive)
  (let ((buf (generate-new-buffer "untitled")))
    (switch-to-buffer buf)
    (funcall (and default-major-mode))
    (setq buffer-offer-save t)))
```

I thought setting "buffer-offer-save" to something not nil would made the trick. But whenever I kill the buffer with "kill-this-buffer", it gets instantly killed without asking anything.

This happens on GNU Emacs 23.1.1

Any ideas?

Thanks,
W

Comment: would associating the buffer to a file, in `new-empty-buffer` solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Edited to add use of `buffers-offer-save`*.  Note: the variable [`buffer-offer-save` is only used upon *exiting* Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/Killing-Buffers.html#index-buffer_002doffer_002dsave-2015).

You can start with this code and customize it to what you want:

```
(add-to-list 'kill-buffer-query-functions 'ask-me-first)
(defun ask-me-first ()
  "prompt when killing a buffer"
  (if (or buffer-offer-save 
          (eq this-command 'kill-this-buffer)
          (and (buffer-modified-p) (not (buffer-file-name))))
      (y-or-n-p (format "Do you want to kill %s without saving? " (buffer-name)))
    t))
```

Upon further reflection, that is a bit heavy-handed because you get prompted for *all* buffers that get killed, and there are often lots of temporary buffers that Emacs uses.  If you just want to be prompted when you try to interactively kill a buffer (that isn't associated with a file).

You can use this advice which only prompts you when you're interactively trying to kill a buffer:

```
(defadvice kill-buffer (around kill-buffer-ask-first activate)
  "if called interactively, prompt before killing"
  (if (and (or buffer-offer-save (interactive-p))
           (buffer-modified-p)
           (not (buffer-file-name)))
      (let ((answ (completing-read
                   (format "Buffer '%s' modified and not associated with a file, what do you want to do? (k)ill (s)ave (a)bort? " (buffer-name))
                   '("k" "s" "a")
                   nil
                   t)))
        (when (cond ((string-match answ "k")
                     ;; kill
                     t)
                    ((string-match answ "s")
                     ;; write then kill
                     (call-interactively 'write-file)
                     t)
                    (nil))
          ad-do-it)

        t)
    ;; not prompting, just do it
    ad-do-it))
```

Comment: would associating the buffer to a file, in `new-empty-buffer` solve the problem?

Comment: @Cheeso Well, doing that in `new-empty-buffer` would put the request at the wrong end, as in when he creates a new buffer.  That said, he could modify `new-empty-buffer` to set a flag that the advice/function could key off.  I guess I liked a solution w/out resorting to using `new-empty-buffer`.

Comment: @Cheeso Note: my updated solution does a better job and pays attention to `new-empty-buffer` - I did a little reading on it (it was new to me, so much to learn).

Comment: @Trey Your *advice* works great. I intuitively get what your code does, but I'll surely study it in greater detail. I'm taking my first steps with Emacs and I'm delighted. Many thanks.

Comment: Just found a weird behavior (don't know if it's reproducible in other installations though). I open a new buffer with M-x new-empty-buffer, paste some text on it, then M-x text-mode, then kill-this-buffer. The buffer gets killed without any warnings.

Comment: @Wintergalt That's because `'kill-buffer` isn't called interactively (`'kill-this-buffer` is, which in turn calls `'kill-buffer`).  *Plus* when you switch major modes, it kills all local variables - thereby resetting `buffer-offer-save` to nil.  See http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Major-Mode-Conventions.html .  I've updated the code above to check for `'kill-this-buffer`.

Comment: Found Trey's defadvice to work great when changing `'new-empty-buffer`. See answer below with the edited `'new-empty-buffer`

Answer (score 1):

Modifying `'new-empty-buffer` seems to make it work as I intended with Trey's defadvice.

```
;; Creates a new empty buffer
(defun new-empty-buffer ()
 "Opens a new empty buffer."
 (interactive)
 (let ((buf (generate-new-buffer "untitled")))
   (switch-to-buffer buf)
   (funcall (and default-major-mode))
   (put 'buffer-offer-save 'permanent-local t)
   (setq buffer-offer-save t)))
```

This makes `buffer-offer-save` permanent local in our new buffer, so it won't get killed with the rest of the local variables when switching major modes.

Answer (score 1):

`buffer-offer-save` asking on exiting Emacs but not on closing a buffer manually doesn't make sense, so why not “enlarge” its responsibilities?

```
(defadvice kill-buffer (around kill-buffer-ask activate)
  "If `buffer-offer-save' is non-nil and a buffer is modified,
prompt before closing."
  (if (and buffer-offer-save (buffer-modified-p))
      (when (yes-or-no-p "The document isn't saved. Quit? ")
        ad-do-it)
    ad-do-it))
```

It will not prompt if `untitled` buffer is newly created. It will not prompt if you use `kill-buffer` from Elisp. It will not prompt on Emacs system buffers like `*Messages*`. But it will prompt if you created an empty buffer and wrote something in it.

See also [my answer on creating an empty buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27446395/596361).